# Alt-Tab pedal with an Arduino

Tags: c#, c++, c, batch-file, arduino

I'm creating an Alt-Tab pedal with an Arduino. The idea is that the user will just press down on a pedal that will hit a button on the Arduino, and this would be the equivalent of hitting the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> key (thereby allowing you to stealthily switch windows).

I'm also open to just minimizing the window.

The problem is, I'm not really sure how to go about this. Should I use a command that runs a batch file? Is there a command in C I can implement this with?  I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: C#, C++ or C?  Keep in mind Arduino.NET exists and run in .NET micro framework.

Comment: I did not know that!  I'll explore that, Thanks a bunch!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}");
```

Or use SendInput() in a C program.

Comment: This works nicely!  But now I'm wondering how to get it to hold down the key?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the other answers, it sounds like you’re proposing to have the Arduino connected to the computer with USB and send a letter when the pedal is pushed, then have a program on the computer side receive that message and invoke Alt-Tab.

There’s a different way to do this: [Teensy 2.0](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/) is an Arduino variant based on the ATmega32U4 microcontroller. This is an AVR chip that has built-in USB support, instead of a serial port that’s translated to USB with a USB-serial bridge as you’ll find on an Arduino.

One of the features is that it can actually [emulate a USB keyboard](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/usb_keyboard.html). You can plug it into a computer and have it send Alt-Tab on a pedal press without writing any software on the computer side, and it will work anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

See this tutorial: http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2011/04/the-awesome-button.html

Basically, it uses an "Easy Button" (you'd use the pedal) to enter a pre-set keyboard character or characters (Alt-Tab in your case) through a USB port.   It should have everything you need to figure out your project.

Comment: I actually already made it, but I'm pretty excited that I made something similar to a MAKE project and didn't end up using their tutorials.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

The Teensy++ is smaller and cheaper than an Arduino and can be hidden in your pedal box, tidy as can be.  A program to do what you desire would take less time than installing the Teensyduino software into the Arduino environment.  I think it is the bomb, particularly for keyboard and MIDI stuff (you could make a pedal for "Start Song" or the all important "All Notes Off").

http://pjrc.com/store/teensy.html

http://pjrc.com/teensy/td_keyboard.html

Answer (score 1):

There are several recipes in *[Arduino Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596802471)* related to using an Arduino to emulate a mouse and/or keyboard.